# Alternative notation to 'y = max(lower bound, min(x, upper bound))'

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I was wondering if there is a more succinct way of writing

\begin{equation}
  y = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \text{lower bound} & x < \text{lower bound} \\
    \text{x} & \text{lower bound} \leq x \leq \text{upper bound} \\
    \text{upper bound} & x > \text{upper bound}
  \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

I thought of $y = \max(\text{lower bound}, \min(x, \text{upper bound}))$ but was wondering if there is perhaps a single function that does the same job.

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen one myself. The form you started with is much clearer, and therefore better for expressing what you mean. Your compact form could be a useful intermediate expression from time to time. You might look at the signal processing literature—they may have more use for such a form than most.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You might be right, clarity is probably better than brevity in this case.